# search form doesn't submits

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this search form:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7tq9146a/1/)

and it doesn't submits. When I click to enter or search icon. why?

```
<form action="/search.php" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <ul class="toolbar clearfix">
            <li><button type="submit" id="btn-search"><span class="fa fa-search" style="color:gray;"></span></button></li>
            <li><input type="search" id="search" placeholder="" name="s"></li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-search').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#search').fadeIn().focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: Because you told it not do do with `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are preventing form submit with `e.preventDefault()`
and not submitting form with any other methods.
You can submit your form using ajax like this:

```
$('#btn-search').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if( $('#search').val() ){
            $.ajax({
                url     : 'submit.php',
                data    : { 'input': $('#search').val() },
                success : function( response ) {
                    alert( response );
                }
            });
        }

        $('#search').animate({
            width: 'toggle',
        }).focus();
    });
```

and write submit functions in `submit.php`
Inside `submit.php` you can write what you need to do with user input. Something like this:

```
<?php 
    echo "You have entered: " . $_GET['input'];
?>
```

Hope this helps..